# @types 404 not found angular2

Tags: angular, typescript, systemjs, esri

**UPDATE**

I've added the code here https://www.dropbox.com/s/g3k4phhqffleeh0/jsapi4-angular2.zip?dl=0 , someone please help :(

**========**

I have an angular 2 project that I forked over and started working on.

Everything was great and dandy until I actually needed to install some types and use them. Intellisense picks up on the typings and can find them. Building isn't an issue either. However SystemJS can't seem to find the typings. I've been battling this for about 10 hours now and can't seem to find a solution :(. Please help.

[Screenshot of chrome console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fBaWw.png)

systemjs.config.js

```
/**
 * System configuration for Angular 2 samples
 * Adjust as necessary for your application needs.
 */
(function (global) {
System.config({
transpiler: 'typescript',

paths: {
  // paths serve as alias
  'npm:': 'node_modules/'
},
// map tells the System loader where to look for things
map: {
  'app': 'app', // 'dist',

  // angular bundles
  '@angular/core': 'npm:@angular/core@2.0.0/bundles/core.umd.js',
  '@angular/common': 'npm:@angular/common@2.0.0/bundles/common.umd.js',
  '@angular/compiler': 'npm:@angular/compiler@2.0.0/bundles/compiler.umd.js',
  '@angular/platform-browser': 'npm:@angular/platform-browser@2.0.0/bundles/platform-browser.umd.js',
  '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic': 'npm:@angular/platform-browser-dynamic@2.0.0/bundles/platform-browser-dynamic.umd.js',
  '@angular/http': 'npm:@angular/http@2.0.0/bundles/http.umd.js',
  '@angular/router': 'npm:@angular/router@3.0.0/bundles/router.umd.js',

  // angular testing umd bundles
  '@angular/core/testing': 'npm:@angular/core@2.0.0/bundles/core-testing.umd.js',
  '@angular/common/testing': 'npm:@angular/common@2.0.0/bundles/common-testing.umd.js',
  '@angular/compiler/testing': 'npm:@angular/compiler@2.0.0/bundles/compiler-testing.umd.js',
  '@angular/platform-browser/testing': 'npm:@angular/platform-browser@2.0.0/bundles/platform-browser-testing.umd.js',
  '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic/testing': 'npm:@angular/platform-browser-dynamic@2.0.0/bundles/platform-browser-dynamic-testing.umd.js',
  '@angular/http/testing': 'npm:@angular/http@2.0.0/bundles/http-testing.umd.js',
  '@angular/router/testing': 'npm:@angular/router@3.0.0/bundles/router-testing.umd.js',

  // other libraries
  'rxjs': 'npm:rxjs@5.0.0-beta.12',
  'angular2-in-memory-web-api': 'npm:angular2-in-memory-web-api',

  'esri': 'http://js.arcgis.com/4.0/esri'
},

// packages tells the System loader how to load when no filename and/or no extension
packages: {
  app: {
    main: './main.js',
    defaultExtension: 'js'
  },
  rxjs: {
    defaultExtension: 'js'
  },
  'angular2-in-memory-web-api': {
    main: './index.js',
    defaultExtension: 'js'
  },
  '@types/highcharts': {defaultExtension: 'ts'}
}
});
})(this);
```

tsconfig.json

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es5",
    "module": "system",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "removeComments": false,
    "lib": [ "es2015", "dom" ],
    "noImplicitAny": false,
    "suppressImplicitAnyIndexErrors": true,
    "typeRoots": ["jsapi4-angular2/node_modules/", "jsapi4-angular2/typings/"]
  },
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules/zone.js",
    "node_modules/concurrently",
    "node_modules/lite-server",
    "node_modules/typescript",
    "node_modules/typings",
    "node_modules/reflect-metadata",
    "node_modules/rxjs",
    "node_modules/tslint",
    "bower_components",
    "typings/main",
    "typings/main.d.ts"
  ]
}
```

esriSystemLoadBrowser.js

```
// load esri modules needed by this application
// into a System.js module called esri
console.log("Loading esri modules: ", esriLoadConfig.modules);
start = performance.now();
esriSystem.register(esriLoadConfig.modules, function () {
  // then bootstrap application
  end = performance.now();
  time = end - start;
  console.log('Loaded esri modules', time / 1000.0);
  System.config({
      transpiler: 'typescript'
  });
  System.import('app/main').then(function () {
    console.log('app/main imported');
  }, function (error) {
    console.log("System import error:", error);
  });
});
```

Comment: You should be trying to hook up the JS file(s) that correspond to the typings, not the typings themselves. Typings are only compile-time. The JS files are for runtime

Comment: Would you happen to know how to do that? Sorry for the dumb question :/

Comment: I've never uses highcharts, so I couldn't say off top of the head. It's something I would need to test out, but I don't have my tools right now.

Comment: its not a problem specific to highcharts, I literally can't include any typing into the project :\

Comment: _"Intellisense picks up on the typings and can find them. Building isn't an issue either."_ - This is the sole purpose of typings. It is not for runtime. You need to install the JS library and add _that_ to the SystemJS config. The JS library is what's used during application runtime, not the typings

Comment: so I added it like this,       "highcharts": "npm:highcharts/highcharts.js",
 for the map and added this to packages object         "highcharts" : {defaultExtension:'js'}, .....but this still happens

Error: (SystemJS) XHR error (404 Not Found) loading http://localhost:3001/@types/highcharts
 ...1
 Error loading http://localhost:3001/@types/highcharts as "@types/highcharts" from http://localhost:3001/app/service/map.service.ts 

it looks like SystemJS is looking for the typings but can't find them :/

Comment: Are you trying to do `import {} from @types/highcharts`? You shouldn't be. Just use `highcharts`

Comment: You should just add `node_modules/@types` to the `typeRoots` in the tsconfig

Comment: I tried that :( I also tried just adding it to types

Answer (score 0):

In the compilerOptions in tsconfig try replacing typeRoots with types explicitly listing the names of the type definition files that it can't find:

`types:[...]`

Also, use `"module": "commonjs"`

Comment: I did what you said but still no success. I also added a path and package value correctly for @types/highcharts. Doing so led me back to where I was. When I removed them and just left the types and module: commonjs then I see this error

 Error loading http://localhost:3003/@types/highcharts.js as "@types/highcharts" from http://localhost:3003/app/service/map.service.ts